# wpf tabitem with image

Tags: wpf, styles, wpf-controls, tabitem

I need to use, with a stile of mahapps.metro, the tabitem with a text and an image..
this is my code:

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource gMetroTabItem}">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Name="img" Height="auto" Width="auto" Source="/myProject;component/Resources/Black_Tools.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="tabItem2" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

and this is the code of the style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="gMetroTabControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="gMetroTabItem">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,6,2" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Label x:Name="root" FontSize="46.67">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Label>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="root" Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                            <Setter  TargetName="root" Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GrayNormal}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="root" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter  TargetName="root" Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Lime" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!--<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>-->
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but doesn't work, 'cause the style go to change a text property, and the image isn't displayed..

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch what I said before. This is much easier.

You only need the TabControl.ItemTemplate. This is what determines the layout of the header. With some tricky binding to ancestor, you can bind to the TabItem's properties for your DataTriggers.

In this example I show how to bind to the IsSelectedProperty. I'll leave the IsMouseOver as an exercise for you. Hint: Bind to the IsMouseOver using ElementName "root", and then in the setter use TargetName="root".

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="gMetroTabControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemHeaderData}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="root" Text="{Binding LabelText}"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding RectFill}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="root" Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="root" Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemHeaderData}">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then you'll need to create a dataobject.

```
public class TabItemHeaderData
{
    public Brush RectColor { get; set; }
    public String LabelText { get; set; }
    public object Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then you just set the values in the dataobject like so.

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource gMetroTabControl}">
    <local:TabItemHeaderData RectColor="Black" LabelText="John">
        <local:TabItemHeaderData.Content>
            <Button>George</Button>
        </local:TabItemHeaderData.Content>
    </local:TabItemHeaderData>
    <local:TabItemHeaderData RectColor="Black" LabelText="John">
    </local:TabItemHeaderData>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: can you post the code please? it work right with the hover and click color of the text?

Comment: Ok. You need to put what the exact problem is in the question. You didn't. You said the image isn't displayed. I assumed the image in the header from the first block of XAML. That image displays fine.

Comment: this is what I see designtime: http://screencast.com/t/TV20zfCi and this is what I see runtime... http://screencast.com/t/7w9rBBEkhMnH

Comment: If you leave the header to just be text. It will fill in the label correctly. That label will highlight like you want. But it's not inside the tab. You'll have to use the HeaderTemplate

Answer (score 1):

From the screencast images you posted:

- designtime: http://www.screencast.com/t/TV20zfCi
- runtime: http://www.screencast.com/t/7w9rBBEkhMnH

This is indicative of the `Black_Tools.png` having incorrect properties. Make sure the image is set to be a resource and copied to the output directory:

- Right Click `Black_Tools.png` in the solution explorer > Properties
- Build Action: Resource
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy always (or Copy if newer)

If the image isn't set as a resource and copied to the output directory, then you'll see the image at design time since the image can be resolved in the solution. However, at runtime, the image path is different since the files will be in the project's output directory.

Comment: What about the "Copy to Output Directory" value?

Comment: I've just used your exact code and everything runs fine with the MahApps styles. I was also able to reproduce the missing image at runtime by cleaning the solution and setting the image build action to none, running the app (no image) and then setting the build action to Resource, running the app (still no image). The resolution was to re-clean the solution, set the build action as Resource, clean again and then run. Everything ran fine.